# Can't apply/compile min-width at breakpoints for Susy

Tags: susy-compass

I'm pretty new to this whole sass/compass/susy thing and tried to follow these intructions: http://susy.oddbird.net/demos/magic/

But I can't get the min-width for the breakpoint working.
When I add the the values to $computer and $tablet, like shown below, it runs into the following error.

> Syntax error: (48em 16) is not a number for `round'
>           on line 59 of /susy/_functions.scss, in`span-columns'

Here's my setup:

```
$total-columns  : 4;             
$column-width   : 4em;            
$gutter-width   : 1em;            
$grid-padding   : $gutter-width;  
// breakpoint var
$tablet: 24em 8;
$computer: 48em 16;

// test container
body {    
    @include container($total-columns, $tablet, $computer);
}
// test element
.test {
    @include span-columns(4, $computer); 
}
```

But if I use it this way...

```
.test {
    @include span-columns(4, 16); 
}
```

...everything works as expected.

Any suggestion what's wrong or has to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span-columns` doesn't take any breakpoint arguments like min-width (though it's an interesting idea). You need to use `at-breakpoint` in order to create your breakpoint, and then use `span-columns` inside of that:

```
.test {
  @include at-breakpoint($computer) {
    // anything inside here will happen at your 48em breakpoint, on a 16-column grid.
    // no need to pass a context to span-columns when that context is the full grid.
    @include span-columns(4);
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I get it! Works like a charm. Thank you very much!